# scrollbar arrows

Tags: keyboard

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit.

After some updates, the arrows on the scrollbar have disappeared.

I looked for a solution, but I couldn't find one.

How can I recover those arrows?

Comment: only in chrome or everywhere?

Comment: Tristan T, no,  everywhere, besides I use Firefox.

Comment: You can change your windows manager. This would not be ideal but it will work.

Comment: Can you give me some advice about which will work?

Answer (score 0):

This will set your scrollbar to the default mode.

```
gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```

Comment: I have this answer:  veronica@veronica-desktop:~$ gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
No existe el esquema «com.canonical.desktop.interface»

Comment: Are you sure you did not upgrade to 16.04?

Comment: I am quite sure. I downloaded 14.04 - 32 bits on a DVD and installed. This happened after some update. To see if it happens on Windows 7(I have it installed too) I installed Firefox and in Windows appears scroll arrows, so this is a problem of Ubuntu.

Comment: I am using in Desktop the option High Contrast and with it I have scrollbar and arrows. it has to be other solution but nobody could tell me about.