# How to activate/install scrollbar steppers 22.04

Tags: gnome, themes, gtk

Scrollbars used to have steppers that could be enabled with `widget.non-native-theme.gtk.scrollbar.allow-buttons True` in the appropriate file.  I cannot find any way to do this in 22.04 .  I can provide whatever details about my window manager, etc, configuration as needed, to address this issue.  (For those who are unfamiliar with the terminology, a scrollbar stepper is the small up triangle arrow at the top of a scrollbar as well as the small down triangle arrow at the bottom of a scrollbar.)  Any assistance would be appreciated.  All of the Ask Ubuntu answers I could find were for much earlier Ubuntu LTS releases and do not seem applicable to the current release and utilities thereof, eg, [scrollbar arrows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781495/scrollbar-arrows)

Comment: Are you certain that you didn't set that in the `about:config` in Firefox to enable those scrollbar steppers?  I just did it in my Firefox and I am running 22.04 and they work fine.

Comment: I just looked at ```about:config``` in the URL search box and read all of the choices (items) related to scroll.  Which is/are the correct entry/ies to change and what are the correct "values" for such change/s?

Comment: Same one you have listed in your question where you change it from False to True.

Comment: That is correct.  Note that in Thunderbird and in Firefox the access to the list of configuration is different.  In Firefox, in the URL entry box, one types ```about:config``` whereas in Tbird Supernova, it is Addons, then Config Button that is an add-on to get to about:config .  Search on "button" in both cases to find the ```widget.non-native-theme.gtk.scrollbar.allow-buttons``` and set to True.  However, the stepper arrows are very small and light grey -- how does one make these "bolder" and "black"?

Comment: I don't know about changing the color of the buttons, but you can make the scrollbar larger which will make the buttons larger by changing the size with the `widget.non-native-theme.scrollbar.size.override` setting.  Start with a low number like `10`.  But, `10` seems to be the default, so maybe try `20`. I think it has to deal with how many pixels wide the scrollbar will be.